# $\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{1}{T-s}}dW(s)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

What is $\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{1}{T-s}}dW(s)$ where $0\le t <T$ and $T \in \mathbb{R}$ and W is a one dimensional brownian motion.

I tried applying Ito's rule with $f(x)= \sqrt{T-x}$. but I did not get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Yes, Ito's rule won't help to my knowledge. That's useful for when you have $W$'s in the integrand. You're actually in the somewhat simpler territory where you don't. Think about it: the $dW_s's$ are independent normals with mean zero and variance $ds$ and they are multiplied by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{T-s}}.$ So you are adding up a bunch of independent normals with mean zero and variance $\frac{ds}{T-s}.$ What do you get?

Comment: Normal random variable with mean zero and variance 1/(T-t)???

Comment: @manhattan Not quite (wrong variance).

Comment: variance is logT/(T-t)?

Comment: @manhattan Hey you're not OP! (but yes)

Comment: what is OP?????

Comment: @manhattan Original poster, i.e. person who asked the question.

Comment: Thanks manhattan and space is dark green

Comment: I should add that I don't believe there's simplified expression for the answer as a random variable (say, in terms of $W_t$ or whatever) so in a sense the question is a bit misleading but this gives its distribution, which is useful.